# Make nginx look for credentials in "Proxy-Authorization" header, so it works with apt

Tags: nginx, apt, http-basic-authentication, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an nginx in front of an apt-cacher-ng. The nginx's job is to terminate HTTPS and take care of authentication.

The issue is, that nginx will look in the `Authorization` header for credentials, but when I configure apt to use a proxy, it will send the credentials in the `Proxy-Authorization` header. So apt gets `401` as a response.

Is there a way to make nginx look for credentials in the `Proxy-Authorization` header?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

Instead of using the `http_proxy` env-variable or `Acquire::http::proxy` in `apt.conf`, I can change the `sources.list` as described in the [apt-cacher-ng documentation](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/%7Ebloch/acng/html/config-servquick.html#config-client) and apt will use the correct header.
For example: `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main` becomes `deb https://apt-cache.example.com/deb.debian.org/debian buster main`

I would still be interested in the "clean" solution, though.